# how to use facebook api on a group

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, tornado

i created an application to test facebook api using Python, then, in the application, i created its **Group**, but, the problem that **this Group dont know who i'm**; it shows me that am the Admin, but when i try to publish something using Tornado, i get the error

```
GraphAPIError: (#210) User not visible
```

and this is because it seems that it deletes the cookie, because when am using the group's profile, then i cant see the GraphAPI since it dont know who is authentificated!

here is the code:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request("/me/home", self.print_callback,access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])
        a = self.current_user["access_token"]
        self.graph = GraphAPI(a)
    def print_callback(self, data):
        self.graph.post_wall(self, "heloooooooo")
```

an sorry, because i dont get well the logic behind users Token, and Groups tokens? here i got a user Token? and because am the admin, i cant post!

EDIT: here are some snapshots i took from the application:

[picture 1](http://s9.postimage.org/jignmk86n/uri.png)
[picture 2](http://s9.postimage.org/v6643d7xr/permissions.png)

Update: i tried this:

```
def print_callback(self, me):
    self.graph.post_wall(self, "helooooo", profile_id="267914489995838")
```

and got the error:

```
self.graph.post_wall(self, "helooooo", profile_id="267914489995838")
TypeError: post_wall() got multiple values for keyword argument 'profile_id'
```

and i used what is in the [Tornado-Facebook-API](https://github.com/pauloalem/tornado-facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook/graphapi.py#L74)

```
def post_wall(self, message, profile_id='me', body=None, **kwargs):
    #XXX move to separate User class?
    body = body or {}
    body['message'] = message
    self._make_request("{0}/feed".format(profile_id), method='POST',
            body=body, **kwargs)
```

update2: here is the full code

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get_current_user(self):
    user_json = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
    if not user_json: return None
    return tornado.escape.json_decode(user_json)

class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
@tornado.web.authenticated
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    self.facebook_request("/me/accounts", self._on_accounts, 
     access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])
    self.a = self.current_user["access_token"]
    self.graph = GraphAPI(self.a)

def _on_accounts(self, account):
    if account is None:
        # Session may have expired
        print "on accounts failed"
        return

    for acc in account["data"]:
        if acc["id"] == "267914489995838":
            print acc["access_token"]
            self.facebook_request("/PAGE_ID/feed", 
               post_args={"message": "Test"}, 
               access_token=acc["access_token"],     
               callback=self.async_callback(self._on_page_post))

def _on_page_post(self, post):
    if not post:
        # Post failed
        return



class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    my_url = (self.request.protocol + "://" + self.request.host +
              "/auth/login?next=" +
              tornado.escape.url_escape(self.get_argument("next", "/")))
    if self.get_argument("code", False):
        self.get_authenticated_user(
            redirect_uri=my_url,
            client_id=self.settings["facebook_api_key"],
            client_secret=self.settings["facebook_secret"],
            code=self.get_argument("code"),
            callback=self._on_auth)
        return
    self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=my_url,
                            client_id=self.settings["facebook_api_key"],
                            extra_params={"scope": "read_stream, publish_stream"})

def _on_auth(self, user):
    if not user:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook auth failed")
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
    self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))


class AuthLogoutHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
def get(self):
    self.clear_cookie("user")
    self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))


class PostModule(tornado.web.UIModule):
def render(self, post):
    return self.render_string("modules/post.html", post=post)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a “group token”. And the rest of your problem description is hard to understand.

Comment: i cant publish anything to the wall, i get the "User not visible" even if am online (the facebook cooki is there, so am logged)

Comment: Are you using a user access token for a user who's in the group, and do you have both the `user_groups` and `publish_stream` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)?

Comment: @Igy ah! so i should add this, because it's written " list of groups the user is a member of" so, as from i understand, facebook will fetch first for the user's groups, then sees if he can post, than write on the wall? do i add the group's name? because it's the application's default group

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'application's default group' - use the /<USER>/groups endpoint to see which groups a user is in, and you can post to /<group>/feed to make a post to that group on behalf of the user

Comment: when i make an application using tornado, i bind it to a link (localhost:8000/auth/login) then, facebook asks me if i want to add a group for this application, i said yes, then i thought that verything will be handled automaticly ?

Comment: stil getting the error, (#210) any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clarifications:

- A #200 error is a permission error. In this case, you don't have permissions to post somewhere.
- There are two main types of tokens: user tokens and page tokens
- You can add a group to an application's roles http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/531/
- As far as I know, there is no way to *add* an application to a group

So I think based on the Facebook id given you either want to do two things

- Post to an application's timeline
- Post to a group via an application

*Posting to an application's timeline*

This requires the application page access token, which you get from `/me/accounts` using the  `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions

```python
self.facebook_request("/me/accounts", self._on_accounts, 
         access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])

def _on_accounts(self, account):
        if account is None:
            # Session may have expired
            print "on accounts failed"
            return

        for acc in account["data"]:
            if acc["id"] == "PAGE_ID":
                print acc["access_token"]
                self.facebook_request("/PAGE_ID/feed", 
                   post_args={"message": "Test"}, 
                   access_token=acc["access_token"],     
                   callback=self.async_callback(self._on_page_post))

def _on_page_post(self, post):
        if not post:
            # Post failed
            return
```

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ for more info

A full example can be seen at https://gist.github.com/3867203 (Which doesn't handle duplicate posting)

Comment: am getting an infinite loop without getting any post! why so? i updated the question, put the whole code

Comment: added extra_params={"scope": "read_stream, publish_stream, manage_pages"} and still get the infinite loop, am sorry am a begginer, and its my first test (using the tornado exemple)

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp An example is given above

Comment: that worked! i'll cry from hapiness , and without any other libraries :D thank you :)

Comment: why do i get a lot of redirections? both Chrome and Firefox stops the page and tell me that there is problem concerning cookies

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp no idea, works fine for me. Though, the code isn't all that great, it could be refactored

Comment: here it makes 5 redirections! (print 5 times "here") and then browser will stop showing the error Erreur 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)